# How to update a service running in a separate process when the Android app is updated?

Tags: java, android, service

When I update the app to a new version, the service that was installed with the previous app version is still running. When I update the app the second time, the updated service is running properly.

However, after first update, whenever i close the app or restart the phone the service from the previous version is running.

How can i force the new service to run as soon as the app is updated.

Here is my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.djuro.updateservicewithappupdate">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:process=":myService" />

        <receiver android:name=".PackageReplacedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.djuro.updateservicewithappupdate"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = App.class.getName();

    private static App mInstance;

    private Messenger myServiceMessenger;
    private boolean isBound;

    private Messenger replyMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = this;
            startMyService();
        }

        isBound = false;

        // start the chore service (if it is not running) and bind to it

    }


    public void startMyService() {
        startService(new Intent(mInstance, MyService.class));
        doBindService();
    }

    public void stopMyService() {
        doUnBindService(true);
        stopService(new Intent(mInstance, MyService.class));
    }



    public static App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Messenger getChoreMessenger() {return mInstance.myServiceMessenger;}


    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        doUnBindService(false);
        super.onTerminate();
    }

    private void doBindService() {
        if (!isBound) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Binding ChoreService.");
            bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            isBound = true;
        }
    }


    private void doUnBindService(boolean restartService) {
        if (isBound) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unbinding ChoreService.");
            if (myServiceMessenger != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.UNREGISTER_CLIENT);
                    msg.replyTo = replyMessenger;
                    replyMessenger.send(msg);
                }
                catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // There is nothing special we need to do if the service has crashed.
                }
            }
            if (restartService) {
                try {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.STOP_SERVICE_ON_UNBIND);
                    msg.replyTo = replyMessenger;
                    replyMessenger.send(msg);
                }
                catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // There is nothing special we need to do if the service has crashed.
                }
            }
            unbindService(myServiceConnection);
            isBound = false;
        } else if (restartService) {
            stopService(new Intent(mInstance, MyService.class));
        }
    }




    private ServiceConnection myServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            myServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
            Log.d(TAG, "connected to service");
            try {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.REGISTER_CLIENT);
                msg.replyTo = replyMessenger;
                myServiceMessenger.send(msg);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                // In this case the service has crashed before we could even do anything with it
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            myServiceMessenger = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "disconnected from ChoreService");
        }
    };

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        }
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getName();

    public static final int UNREGISTER_CLIENT = 1;
    public static final int REGISTER_CLIENT = 2;
    public static final int STOP_SERVICE_ON_UNBIND = 3;

    final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

    private String appVersion;
    private boolean stopOnUnbind;
    private int boundCount = 0;


    // called when the intent starts the Service
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        getVersion();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    // called once at creation (before onStartCommand)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    // used to bind intent to service
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //doStopForeground();
        boundCount ++;
        Log.d(TAG, "bound count: " + boundCount);
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        boundCount --;
        Log.d(TAG, "bound count: " + boundCount);
        boolean result = super.onUnbind(intent);
        if (stopOnUnbind) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stopSelf()");
            stopSelf();
        }
        return result;
    }

    // called when the service is destroyed
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }



    public void getVersion() {
        try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            appVersion = pInfo.versionName;
            Log.d(TAG, "appVersion: " + appVersion);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IncomingHandler handling message. msg.what= " + msg.what);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case STOP_SERVICE_ON_UNBIND:
                    stopOnUnbind = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PackageReplacedReceiver.java

```
public class PackageReplacedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = PackageReplacedReceiver.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "package updated");
        App.getInstance().stopMyService();
    }

}
```

Comment: "the service that was installed with the previous app version is still running" -- how exactly have you determined this? Your service returns `START_STICKY`, so it should be automatically restarted sometime after your application updates.

Comment: I'm logging the version of the service in the MyService.onStart(). The method name is getVersion(). Also on my testing i add a single Log line of code with a number. I increase that number with a new version to see if it has been updated.

Comment: I tried also restarting the app after first update, and it's still running the old version of the service. I also tried with NOT_STICKY and it did no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED action in your intent filer and stop your service from broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageReplacedReceiver" android:enabled="@bool/is_at_least_api_12" > <intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
 </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: I tried this also, and as you can see there is a broadcast receiver that is tied to the on PACKAGE_REMOVED. The service will not stop unless it has no context bound. Hence this code. This event is triggered and i saw it with online logging (you can check with logging to file).

Comment: It's strange that why os is not killing your application after successful update. Os should restart the application and Application extended class should call. You just try from you Application class and restart your service if package relaced